# Memory leaks with tkinter partial and lambda command

Tags: memory

need your help. My program, using python 3.7.3 tkinter GUI, continues to build up in memory - memory leaks, that is called I believe, I narrowed down the problem in my code and it seems like the problem is within command function.
The program analyses reply from serial console and if criteria met changes the color and command function of the button. 
Loop I run to read serial console is:

```
def list_ser():
if ser_connect == 1:
    try:
        send_com('R_S')
    except:
        print('Serial port is close!')
window.after(1000, list_ser)
```

buttons to configure:

```
 if var1.find('D02_1')>=1:
    btn02.configure(text = 'D02 IS ON', bg='YELLOW', font=("Verdana", 13, "bold"), command=lambda: send_com('D02_0'))
if var1.find('D02_0')>=1:
    btn02.configure(text = 'D02 IS OFF', bg='GREY', font=("Verdana", 13, "bold"), command=lambda: send_com('D02_1'))
if var1.find('D02_2')>=1:
    btn02.configure(text = 'D02 PWM CONTROL', bg='GREEN', font=("Verdana", 13, "bold"), command=lambda: send_com('D02_0'))
```

if I comment {command=lambda: send_com('D02_0')} everything is working fine without increase of the ram memory. I have tried {partial} function, but no result, I have tried {destroy()} {delete()} functions, no result.
What is the current problem, please help to understand

Comment: what is in send_com function?

Comment: Just a simple command to send data through serial port to receive response string of data    'code'     def send_com(com1):
        ArduinoSerial.write(com1.encode()) # set Arduino output pin 13 high
        var1 = ArduinoSerial.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
        writeLog(var1 + '\n') 'code'